# How do I fix: Notice: Undefined index?

Tags: php, undefined-index

My code (below) throws a notice, but I don't know how to fix it

> Undefined index in Session, ...

```
<?php

    if($_SESSION['snt'] && $_SESSION['sps']){
        echo "<font color=orange>" . "Selamat Datang " . $_SESSION["snt"] . "<a href='?ak=logout'> LOGOUT </a>" . "</font>";
    } else {
        echo "<a href='?ak=form_login'> LOGIN </a>";
    }

?>
```

Notice:

> Notice: Undefined index: snt in C:\xampp\htdocs\Dota2\FUNGSI\login.php on line 2

Comment: Where is your `session_start();` ?

Comment: newbie error @Rizier123 *meep meep*

Comment: my session_start in index .php,.. but this notice in login.php,.

Comment: Do you include `login.php` into `index.php` somehow?

Comment: Yeah,. right ,.. But this notice fixed

Comment: *Simple:* - you haven't defined it. Show full code and where it does get assigned if you have defined it.